# 'Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0' when parsing JSON file using java

Tags: java, json, jar

I am writing a Minecraft plugin, which gets packaged to a .jar file and I'm trying to parse a JSON file using the json-simple package, but I run into a 'Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0' Exception.

Here is the method causing the problem, specifically the 'Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);' line.

```
private JSONObject openJSON() {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        FileReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader(filepath);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            Bukkit.getLogger().warning("[BetterSafety] verifiedPlayers.json file not found, creating new file.");
            return createJSON();
        }

        try {
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
            if(jsonObj.containsKey("verifiedPlayers")) {
                verifiedUUIDsJSONArray = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("verifiedPlayers");
            } else {
                Bukkit.getLogger().warning("[BetterSafety] The verifiedPlayers array could not be found in the verifiedPlayers.json file, creating new file.");
                return createJSON();
            }

            return (JSONObject) obj;
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            Bukkit.getLogger().severe("[BetterSafety] An error occurred when trying to parse the verifiedPlayers.json file: \n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have also checked my JSON formatting and it should be fine as far as I know:

```
{
  "verifiedPlayers":[]
}
```

I also previously had problems with my file path, since I was packaging it into a .jar and didn't use the correct path, so maybe it could also be related to this:

```
private String filepath = new File("verifiedPlayers.json").getAbsolutePath();
```

I tried looking for threads with similar problems and most of them mentioned, that it's likely to do something with the JSON formatting, but when I tried checking it with https://jsonlint.com/ it told me everything is fine.

Thanks for any potential help!

Comment: Files don't exist within jar files, only resources, and so you should read the text as a resource, not as a file.